# Understanding model.summary in Tensorflow and making a model visualisation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, visualization

I am trying to make a model visualization like this: [image: Take from http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html]

The image is taken from http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html

**This is my code:**

```
def create_classical_model():
    # A simple model based off LeNet from https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, [3, 3], activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, [3, 3], activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return model


model = create_classical_model()
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

**Output**

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1179776   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,198,721
Trainable params: 1,198,721
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Can somebody help me with how to find Depth, Height, Width, filter Height, filter Width for every layer and when to use vector length?

Answer (score 0):

I used this tool before to visualize models too.

I made a visualization of the given model in the question.

- Depth is the number of channels for the input layer, and is the number of filters in the convolution layers.
- Height and width are the height and width of the matrix
- filter height and width : height and width used for the convolution filter
- For  the Flatten and dense layers: You only have to add number of perceptrons.

Note: For dense layers with a high number of perceptrons, like your case 9216, the visualization will disappear on the website. The solution for this, is to use first a low number like 256 instead of 9216, and then download the svg file, and open it in Notepad, find 256 and replace it with 9216. Then you can open the svg file on the browser to see the right architecture.

Params:

[image: Architecture of the given model]

Result:

[image: Result]